# Parse YAML as map of struct with array of sub struct

Tags: go, yaml

I am using github.com/goccy/go-yaml to read YAML values using PATH

sample yaml file

```
tree:
  branch:
    slices:
      slice1:
        - w: 1
        - w: 2
          h: 3
      slice2:
        - w: 11
          h: 22
```

I am using following code to unmarshal it using YAML path

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/goccy/go-yaml"
)

type slice struct {
    W int
    H int
}

type sliceObject struct {
    Slices []slice
}

func main() {
    yml := `
tree:
  branch:
    slices:
      slice1:
        - w: 1
        - w: 2
          h: 3
      slice2:
        - w: 11
          h: 22
`

    pathStr := "$.tree.branch.slices"
    path, err := yaml.PathString(pathStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to construct YAML path %s", err)
    }

    var sl map[string]sliceObject
    if err := path.Read(strings.NewReader(yml), &sl); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to read value for path %s error %+v", pathStr, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("object: %+v", sl)
}
```

above code fails with following error

```
  - failed to get map node:
    github.com/goccy/go-yaml.(*Decoder).keyToNodeMap
        /Users/.../go/pkg/mod/github.com/goccy/go-yaml@v1.11.2/decode.go:977
  - [2:9] sequence was used where mapping is expected:
    github.com/goccy/go-yaml.errUnexpectedNodeType
        /Users/.../go/pkg/mod/github.com/goccy/go-yaml@v1.11.2/decode.go:542
```

but same code works perfectly if I change `var sl map[string]sliceObject` to `var sl map[string][]slice`

I really don't want to add another level in the YAML.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are defining a `sliceObject` to contain a `Slices` property, you need to add an additional level called `slices` after you declare the `slice1` and `slice2` instances of `sliceObject`:

```
...
type sliceObject struct {
    Slices []slice
}

func main() {
    yml := `
tree:
  branch:
    slices:
      slice1:   // <<< A sliceObject instance
        slices: // <<< A sliceObject.Slices property
          - w: 1
          - w: 2
            h: 3
      slice2:   // <<< A sliceObject instance
        slices: // <<< A sliceObject.Slices property
          - w: 11
            h: 22
`

    pathStr := "$.tree.branch.slices"
    path, err := yaml.PathString(pathStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to construct YAML path %s", err)
    }

    var sl map[string]sliceObject
    if err := path.Read(strings.NewReader(yml), &sl); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to read value for path %s error %+v", pathStr, err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("object: %+v", sl)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run .
object: map[slice1:{Slices:[{W:1 H:0} {W:2 H:3}]} slice2:{Slices:[{W:11 H:22}]}]
```

However, since you don't want to add another layer, you can simply define `sliceObject` as a slice of `slice` types (personally not recommended because it can get confusing, it should work:

```
...
type sliceObject []slice

func main() {
    yml := `
tree:
  branch:
    slices:
      slice1:  // A sliceObject with two slices below
        - w: 1
        - w: 2
          h: 3
      slice2:  // A sliceObject with one slice below
        - w: 11
          h: 22
`


    pathStr := "$.tree.branch.slices"
    path, err := yaml.PathString(pathStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to construct YAML path %s", err)
    }

    var sl map[string]sliceObject
    if err := path.Read(strings.NewReader(yml), &sl); err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed to read YAML %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("object: %+v", sl)

}
```

Output:

```
$ go run .
object: map[slice1:[{W:1 H:0} {W:2 H:3}] slice2:[{W:11 H:22}]]
```

BTW, the reason why changing `var sl map[string]sliceObject` to `var sl map[string][]slice` works is because you basically tell the parser to look for ways to convert `slice1` and `slice2` into `[]slice` instead of `Slices` (again, because you are missing the `slices` key) -- it's basically the same as redefining a `sliceObject` to simply a `[]slice`, as shown in the second code sample above

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need to define `sliceObject` as a struct. Instead you can modify as below to make it work:

```
type sliceObject []slice
```